# Passing an anonymous function as an argument to another function PHP

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to pass an anonymous function as an argument to another function, but I'm getting an error: "Value of type null is not callable in". What am I doing wrong?
The number of passed anonymous functions may vary.

```
    function sfunc($a, ...$funcs){
        echo '<details> <summary>'. $a . '</summary>' . PHP_EOL;
        foreach ($funcs as $func)
            $func();
        unset($func);
        echo '</details>' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    $fun = function (){
        echo "123";
    };

<?php
    sfunc($summary, $fun() );
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a reference to the function like this:

```
sfunc($summary, $fun);
```

Live demo: https://3v4l.org/tS8DX

**Explanation**

By writing `$fun()` (with the brackets) you're not passing in the function reference, you're first *executing* the function and passing in the *result* of that function's execution. Since that function doesn't `return` anything, then that result is `null` - hence the error message. (N.B. Even if it did return something, passing the returned value still wouldn't achieve what you're trying to do.)